# tensor flow while nesting

Tags: tensorflow, while-loop

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np



x1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0, shape=[2, 2]))


ret1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0, shape=[2, 2]))
ret2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0, shape=[2, 2]))

def condition1(i1,x1):
    return tf.less(i1, 2)
def condition2(i2,x2):
    return tf.less(i2, 2)

def body1(i1,x1):
    i2 = tf.constant(0)
    a= tf.constant(np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]]), dtype=tf.int32)
    b = tf.constant(np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]]), dtype=tf.int32)
    x1 = a + b
    i1=tf.add(i1,1)

    def body2(i2,x1):        
        a= tf.constant(np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]]), dtype=tf.int32)
        x1=x1 + a
        return i2,x1

    index,ret2=tf.while_loop(condition2, body2, loop_vars=[i2,x1])


    return i1,x1


i1 = tf.constant(0)
index,ret1=tf.while_loop(condition1, body1,  loop_vars=[i1,x1])    
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)   
    print(sess.run(ret1))
    print(sess.run(ret2))
    sess.close()
```

I want to create nested while-loop. My variable ret2 don't are returning [[3,3],[3,3]], but  ret1 are ok [[2,2],[2,2]] . why my variable ret2 is returning [[0,0],[0,0]]? Help me please!

Comment: There are two Python objects called `ret2` in your program. The first is the `tf.Variable()` that you create and initialize with zeros. The second is a local variable in the `body1()` function whose value is not used. When you `print(sess.run(ret2))` you are printing the value of the `tf.Variable`, which still has its initial value (`[[0, 0], [0, 0]]`) because no operations that update it have been executed.

Comment: Note that the same is true of `ret1`.  You can comment out the lines where you declare `ret1` and `ret2` to be `tf.Variable` and your code will run the same.